# Самый эффективный способ поиска в массивах?

Tags: javascript, jquery, алгоритм, веб-программирование

Есть 2 масива(очень больших). Искомое значение (только одно) находится в одном из них. Нужен какой-то хороший алгоритм поиска.

Не хотелось бы перебирать сначала один массив полностью, потом, если искомого значения там нет, запускать второй перебор.

Насколько эффективным было бы запускать поиск по 2 массивам одновременно с точки зрения производительности?

Цель найти оптимальный способ (наименее ресурсоёмкий и наиболее быстрый).

Какие алгоритмы поиска будут эффективными в такой ситуации?

Comment: А в чём смысл? В худшем случае все равно будет n+m итераций

Comment: Такой поиск происходит однократно в массиве? Или это регулярная операция? Можно ли с этими массивами что-то сделать заранее? Например отсортировать?

Comment: яваскрипт - однопоточен, и нужно очень постараться, чтобы запустить поиск _сразу_ в двух массивах.

Comment: что хранится в массивах?

Comment: @hedgehogues Поиск происходит многократно.Можно отсортировать

Comment: Отсортируйте массивы, и бинарным поиском.

Comment: @Grundy В масивах строки

Comment: если не production, а песочница, то можно попробывать webassembly :) P.S. поддерживаются последние версии Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: Да, тогда, пожалуй, бинарным поиском проходить -- оптимальнее всего. Кроме того, можно построить хеш-мапу, которая будет за O(1) проверить есть ли в массиве конкретное значение или нет.

Comment: @hedgehogues, тогда и массив не нужен :-)

Comment: Нужно найти символ или подстроку? Хранить нужно именно в массивах?

Comment: объедини в один массив, отсортируй и бинарисерчем ищи

Comment: @hedgehogues, масив вида m =["банан", "апельсин", "малина"], искомое значение например "малина". Хранить можно и в обектах

Comment: @Kiril1995 тогда тебе подойдёт префиксное дерево, думаю

Comment: Я бы ратовал за сортированный хэш-мап. Общий на оба массива.

Comment: Если нужно просто проверять входит ли слово в набор или нет - используй просто объект вместо массива: ключами объекта будут необходимые строки, значениями могут быть любые значения, например _true_

Comment: Всем спасибо буду тестировать все методы

Comment: мне аж интересно стало, что значит "очень большой массив"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения Вашей задачи можно предложить несколько методов: бинарный поиск по полиномиальному хэшу, префиксное дерево.

Полиномиальные хэши. 
Хэш-функция -- это отображение, ставящее в соответствие некоторому объекту число. В нашем случае -- строку. Полиномиальные хэши -- это полином. Вообще говоря, можно брать любые функции. Но в таком случае может оказаться, что для двух элементов (строк) у нас есть два одинаковых объекта. Полиномиальные функции сводят этот риск в минимум. Считаются они так:

```
f(строка) = строка[0] + строка[1] ^ 2 + строка[2] ^ 3 + ... + строка[n- 1]^(n-1),
```

где строка[i]  -- код символа.

Как можно заметить, здесь происходит много вычислений со степенями. Это не есть хорошо. Если нужна скорость, то можно применить быстрое возведение в степень. Кроме того, оказывается, что большие степени -- это большие числа, меньшая скорость и больше памяти, поэтому полиномиальный хэш можно брать по модулю:

`[f(строка)]_k`, где `k` -- большое простое число, а операция `[.]` -- взятие остатка от деления. Подробнее [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/142589/), [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/string_hashes) и [вот здесь](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/17507).

Замечу, что взятие остатка от деления можно проводить от каждого слагаемого отдельно:

```
f(строка) = [строка[0]] + [строка[1]] ^ 2 + [строка[2]] ^ 3 + ... + [строка[n- 1]]^(n-1)
```

Таким образом, посчитав хэши, упорядочим строки по нему. После чего сделаем сортировку по хэшу. В отсортированном массиве можно искать нужный элемент бинарным поиском. Тогда время работы O(max(log N, log M)), где M, N -- длины строк.

Префиксное дерево
Данное дерево содержит все префиксы строк. Тогда можем осуществить поиск в дереве за O(max(максимальная длина строки)).

[Префиксное дерево (Trie)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Comment: Хэш (как структура) без вариантов разрешения коллизий - штука неюзабельная в принципе. Хэши  с ключами, которые вычисляются как полиномиальный хэш, слишком медленные.

Comment: Почему она не юзабельная? Нам нужно бинарный поиск сделать. Число коллизий будет небольшое относительно общего размера. Ничего плохого в этом нет.

Comment: Может я не так понял. Я говорю о хэш-таблице, а вы, получается, о массиве пар "хэш-функция + значение", который потом нужно отсортировать? Но это уже слишком громоздко и медленно получается, IMHO. По сравнению с деревом точно.

Comment: Да, Вы правильно прокомментировали.

Answer (score 4):

Для поиска строк самая быстрая структура - тернарное дерево. Любые другие варианты будут заведомо хуже, и их в этом контексте обсуждать нет смысла.

Реализации для JS есть, например [tritium](https://github.com/ryankask/tritium). Из примеров оттуда:

```
tritium = require('tritium');
tree    = tritium.ternarySearchTree();

tree.add('airplane');
tree.add('airport');
tree.add('airside');
tree.add('apple');

tree.has('air');     // true
tree.has('apple');   // true
tree.has('apples');  // false

tree.prefixSearch('airp'); // [ 'airplane', 'airport' ]
tree.prefixSearch('air');  // [ 'airplane', 'airport', 'airside' ]
tree.prefixSearch('be');   // []
```

Comment: За сколько работает тернарное дерево? Что-то мне кажется, что это будет дольше, чем префиксное

Comment: @hedgehogues, что-то мне кажется вы оба перемудрили. Судя по комментарию, ему нужно просто проверить _конкретное_ значение без вариаций, то есть нет смысла городить огород с префиксами и деревьями

Comment: @hedgehogues, это и есть частный случай префиксного :)

Comment: @Grundy, в условии есть не только поиск, но и *быстрый* поиск по *очень большому* массиву строк. Ничего лучше тернарного (ok, в общем случае префиксного) дерева пока для этого не придумали. И потом, с чего вы взяли что оно не подходит для поиска конкретного значения? Очень даже подходит.

Comment: @PinkTux, я к тому, что нет смысла вручную это делать, когда есть обычный объект, у которого можно быстро проверить наличие строкового ключа.